# Fluent NHibernate - query hierarchy data from the bottom

Tags: c#, nhibernate

For example if I have a table like this

```
id  | parent_id
-----------------
1   | null
2   | 1
3   | 1
4   | 1
5   | 2
6   | 3
7   | 3
8   | 4
9   | 7
....
```

The hierarchy tree will look like this:

```
                           X1
                           |
 ------------------------------------------------------
 |                         |                          |
 X2                        X3                         X4
 |                         |                          |
 |                ------------------                  |
 |                |                |                  |
 X5               X6               X7                 X8 
                                   |
                                   X9
```

So, is there anyway that I can query using `QueryOver` or `Criteria` that when I input the `id`, it will return the list of all the `parent_id` (or parent object) from its parent to the top? For example:

```
input | result
-----------------------
1     | null
2     | [1]
3     | [1]
5     | [2, 1]
8     | [4, 1]
9     | [7, 3, 1]
....
```

==================

Working query (but have to call database twice)

```
var roleIds = session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT Id FROM dbo.fn_get_parent_roles(:id)")
                .SetInt32("id", roleId)
                .List<int>();

Role x = null;
var query = session.QueryOver<Role>(() => x)
    .Where(Restrictions.In("x.RoleId", roleIds.ToArray()));
```

==================

Updated:

```
var hierarchyQuery = new SQLCriterion(
                new SqlString("{alias}.RoleId IN (SELECT Id FROM dbo.fn_get_parent_roles(:id))"),
                new object[] { roleId },
                new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.Int32 });
var results = session.QueryOver<Role>()
            .Where(hierarchyQuery)
            .List();
```

Then I got this message:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

Here is full StackTrace

```
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at NHibernate.Criterion.SQLCriterion.ToSqlString(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.GetWhereCondition(IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker..ctor(IOuterJoinLoadable persister, CriteriaQueryTranslator translator, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory, ICriteria criteria, String rootEntityName, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaLoader..ctor(IOuterJoinLoadable persister, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory, CriteriaImpl rootCriteria, String rootEntityName, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(CriteriaImpl criteria, IList results)
   at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List(IList results)
   at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List[T]()
   at NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`1.List()
   at NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`1.NHibernate.IQueryOver<TRoot>.List()
   at At2ClaimBO.Src.Repositories.UserRepo.GetUsers(String searchStr, Int32 roleId, Int32 page) in D:\Arunsawad\At2ClaimBO\At2ClaimBO\Src\Repositories\UserRepo.cs:line 85
   at At2ClaimBO.Src.Services.ClaimService.GetUsers(String searchStr, Int32 roleLevel, Int32 page) in D:\Arunsawad\At2ClaimBO\At2ClaimBO\Src\Services\ClaimService.cs:line 1326
   at At2ClaimBO.Controllers.AdminController.SearchHead(String search_str, String role_id, Int32 page) in D:\Arunsawad\At2ClaimBO\At2ClaimBO\Controllers\AdminController.cs:line 259
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate does not support this natively - you would have to use something like a table valued function and a SQL Query:

Assuming you are using MSSQL server, and a version which supports table valued functions (probably 2008 onwards?):

SQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnGetParents(@id INT)
    RETURNS @tbl TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL)
    AS
BEGIN       
    ;WITH t AS (
        SELECT ParentId AS Id
        FROM Hierarchy
        WHERE Id = @id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ParentId
        FROM Hierarchy
        INNER JOIN t ON t.Id = Hierarchy.Id
    ) 
    INSERT INTO @tbl
    SELECT DISTINCT Id FROM t
    WHERE Id IS NOT NULL

    RETURN;
END
```

and then to get the results:

```
session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT Id FROM dbo.fnGetParents(:id)")
    .SetInt32("id", id)
    .List<int>();
```

If you want to include it in a Criteria or QueryOver function, you can use a SQLCriteria or SQLProjection, eg:

```
 var hierarchyQuery = new SQLCriterion(
                          new SqlString("{alias}.id IN (SELECT Id FROM dbo.fnGetParents(?))"),
                          new object[] {id}, 
                          new[] {NHibernateUtil.Int32});
 var results = session.QueryOver<Hierarchy>()
          .Where(hierarchyQuery)
          .List();
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer :)

Comment: Oh, how can I add this result to Where clause of QueryOver, I want to get the objects that has id which is in the list that returned from this function, I have tried Restrictions.In and SubQueries but no luck :(

Comment: I figured it out, but it sends 2 separated calls to database, is there anyway that I can combine them into one call?

Comment: I have added an example of how you can get all the entities in the hierarchy using a SQLCriterion

Comment: I have tried exactly as you said, but I keep getting this error: `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index`. Is there anything that I did wrong?

Comment: Can you update your question with the full query and the full exception + stack trace?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the SQLCriterion - the parameter needs to be ? instead of :id because you can't specify named parameters into the SQL criterion - I have updated the answer

Comment: Still no luck, I think it's a bug of SQLCriterion, I have changed query to this one and it worked: `var hierarchyQuery = new SQLCriterion(new SqlString("{alias}.RoleId IN (SELECT Id FROM dbo.fn_get_parent_roles(" + roleId + "))"), new object[0], new IType[0]);`
Thank you so much for your time. Have a nice day!